# Replace an item in webSQL database with a new item if it has the same date

Tags: javascript, database, web-sql, html-framework-7

I have an input field for a title and a note, and the date is created automatically based on the current date. However, I would like the database to update so that if there is an item in the database already with today's date, any new item of the same date will replace it. Is this possible, or will I have to make due with having several entries with the same date?

```
document.getElementById("hide").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("enterBtn").addEventListener("click", addEntry);
document.getElementById("display").addEventListener("click", display);
document.getElementById("hide").addEventListener("click", hidden);
//document.getElementById("listDiv2").innerHTML = " ";

//var date = new Date();
//date = new Date(date).toUTCString();
//date = date.split(' ').slice(0, 5).join(' ');


if (window.openDatabase) {
    //Create the database the parameters are 1. the database name 2.version 
    number 3. a description 4. the size of the database( in bytes) 1024 x 1024 = 1 MB
    var mydb = openDatabase("wellness", "0.1", "Wellness App", 1024 * 1024);

    //create the entry table using SQL for the database using a transaction
    mydb.transaction(function(t) {
        t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes (id INTEGER PRIMARY 
            KEY ASC, v_date TEXT, title TEXT, note TEXT)
        ");
    });

} else {
    myApp.alert("init if statement error");
}


//function to output the list of entry in the database

function updateEntryList(transaction, results) {
    //initialise the listitems variable

    var listitems = " ";

    var listholder = document.getElementById("listDiv2");

    //clear entry list ul
    listholder.innerHTML = " ";

    var i;

    //Iterate through the results
    for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

        var row = results.rows.item(i);

        listholder.innerHTML += "<li>" + "<p>" + '<h2>' + '<u>' + row.title +
            '</u>' + '</h2>' + "<p>" + '<h3>' + 'Note: ' + row.note + '</h3>' + "<p>" +
            row.v_date + "<p>" + "__________________" + "</li>";
    }
}

function clearText() {
    //document.getElementById('v_date').value = '';
    document.getElementById('title').value = '';
    document.getElementById('note').value = '';
}

//function to get the list of entry from the database

function outputEntry() {
    //check to ensure the mydb object has been created
    if (mydb) {
        //Get all the entry from the database with a select statement, set 
        outputEntryList as the callback
        function
        for the executeSql command
        mydb.transaction(function(t) {
            t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM notes", [], updateEntryList);
            //myApp.alert("outputEntry called");
        });
    } else {
        myApp.alert("outputEntry error");
    }
}


function display() {
    outputEntry();
    document.getElementById("display").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("listDiv2").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("hide").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function hidden() {
    document.getElementById("display").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("listDiv2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("hide").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
//function to add the car to the database

function addEntry() {
    //check to ensure the mydb object has been created
    if (mydb) {
        //myApp.alert("if statement good");
        //var d = new Date();
        //var date = d.toDateString();
        //get the values of the make and model text inputs
        //var v_date = document.getElementById("v_date").value;
        var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
        var note = document.getElementById("note").value;

        v_date = new Date;
        v_date = new Date(v_date).toUTCString();
        v_date = v_date.split(' ').slice(0, 4).join(' ')

        //date = new Date(date).toUTCString();
        //date = date.split(' ').slice(0, 5).join(' ');

        //myApp.alert("all elements got by id");

        //Test to ensure that the user has entered both a make and model
        if (title !== "" && note !== "") {

            //Insert the user entered details into the entry table, note the use 
            of the ? placeholder, these will replaced by the data passed in as an
            array as the second parameter
            mydb.transaction(function(t) {
                t.executeSql("INSERT INTO notes (v_date, title, note) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [v_date, title, note]);

                myApp.alert("Your Entry Added");
            });
        } else {
            myApp.alert("You must enter values!");
        }

    } else {
        myApp.alert("add entry error");
    }
    clearText();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a string as primary key?

```
var date = new Date();
var key = date.getFullYear() + date.getMonth() + date.getDate()
```

and use this key with INSERT OR REPLACE INTO